# Azure Web App and sticky session with Affinity Cookie – Reliable?

Tags: session-variables, azure-web-app-service

I did a production release for one of my clients with Azure PAAS – Azure Web App (formerly Azure Websites). We marked the site in Auto scale mode with 2 minimum instances. We started getting complains from the users that intermittently users are experiencing some issues which can cause only if they lose the session variables while actively using the site.

We were wondering how that can happen since we are maintaining the sessions in "in proc". We didn’t go for a separate out of proc session manager (Redis cache / DB based) on the day 1 because, according to the documentation, Azure Web app runs with a sticky session load balancer (when running with multiple instances) by default. It injects ARR affinity cookie in the Http response that helps in redirecting a user to the same instance with which it established the session at the first time.

To debug this issue, we started printing the actual sessionId in the page. After many attempts, we reproduced the issue – surprisingly sessions are getting swapped. Lets say – my session Id is “1eocgtmwwwwvs1cxksyofne4”, after the page refreshes it got changed to “5p1hsxszq2mcqmt5i5ytqg12” including all other information that are managed in session variable. Scary… isn’t it?

Reached out to support with an Emergency ticket – the response is:

"Azure Web Apps is a stateless platform and our recommendations is to implement a Session Management solution that best works for your environment and avoid the dependency on In-memory session state management especially in cases where your Web App is hosted on multiple servers . In your case as you are considering to implement a Caching solution for session management in near future , our recommendation is to move to a single instance as a workaround for now . We will assist you in ensuring that the app is working as expected on a single instance.”

I completely understand that – but why Affinity cookie will fail. I know that Affinity cookie can be disabled and I didn’t disable it. I thought of sharing this story. It could be useful for any other person relying on Affinity cookie based sticky load balancer.

BTW: Redis session provider implementation is very easy. It took just a few mins to implement.

Doing a postmortem now – what went wrong? I didn’t consider the cookie ‘not supported’ browsers. Then why would it fail intermittently even in my browser where I support cookie. PAAS resources are constantly in move / getting swapped .. .. and there is no way we can use in proc session … etc

Comment: Affinity cookie can change when there is a service upgrade or a an issue with the machine assigned to you. By design it is the best effort approach, but a site cannot rely on that = the affinity cookie shouldn't change very often, but it can change.

Regarding the session id. Do you have anything special regarding handling your sessions? Are you saying that your session got swapped with a different existing session or a new one got created? I can see how new one got created, but swapping with a different one would be much more worrying.

Comment: You said you turned on Autoscale.  Something that comes to mind is that suppose you had 3 instances running.  Now, suppose that Autoscale is triggered to scale down your instances to 2. If you had users who's ARR Affinity cookie is from the instance being removed, then that could result in you seeing a different ARR Affinity cookie as a new session is established on one of the other instances.

Comment: "Azure Web app runs with a sticky session load balancer". Do you have a official Microsoft source on that? The statement seems to be correct as far as my tests proves, but I would like to have it confirmed. Thank you.